# 403 forbidden message while executing a rest message through Jmeter

Tags: rest, jmeter

I am trying to test a Rest service through HTTP sampler using Jmeter. The first sampler generates a token and I am using this token for authorization in the header manager of another HTTP sampler "GetUserandPolicies"(Rest WS request) using RegEx and ForEach controller. I can see in the view results tree that RegEx is working fine passing the actual token to the next request. But the Rest Request is failing giving a response message as Forbidden and Response Code 403 which means that the server is able to recognise the request but denying the access.There is no port number for this HTTP sampler which I suspect would be the culprit. But, the same test is passing with another tool (iTKO LISA) without any port value. Both the samplers "TokenGeneration" and "GetUserandPolicies" have no port values. I need some help on this. I am using the POST method in the HTTP  sampler

Please find the sampler result:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-01-13 12:12:29 IST
Load time: 1390
Latency: 1390
Size in bytes: 382
Headers size in bytes: 354
Body size in bytes: 28
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 28
Date: Mon, 13 Jan 2014 06:42:30 GMT
```

HTTPSampleResult fields:

```
ContentType: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: May I advice you to compare the headers sent by `iTKO LISA` and the Jmeter samplers ?

Comment: ok.. will see to it and get back

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type` stanza I guess that you're missing proper `Authorization` header.

In regards to empty port everything is fine, it defaults to port 80 in case of HTTP and 443 in case of HTTPS

There are 2 options on how you can deal with [Basic HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

1. Pass username and password in URL like `protocol://username:password@host:port/path`
   i.e. http://user:pass@your.server.com/somelocation
2. Use JMeter [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) to construct required "Authorization" header for you.

In case if your authentication system uses other approaches, i.e. Cookie-based, NTLM or Kerberos it's still possible but a little bit more tricky. If so - update this post with all details you can get (i.e. request details) and don't hesitate to leave a comment requesting for more input

Comment: Sorry for the dalay..I was off for 2 days.. Thanks for the suggestion. We are using Rest WS and we don't have any authentication.. Https Protocol is used and there is no username or password required for the WS request. Actually the code is getting re-deployed.Will get back with more deatils if the test fails again after that